# jgit - git diff based on file extension

Tags: java, git, jgit

I am using JGit API (https://www.eclipse.org/jgit/) to access a git repository.

In the git repository, I am storing .txt files and other file formats also. I ran into a requirement where I should get the diff of only .txt files.

Basically I am trying to achieve the equivalent of

```
git diff master HEAD -- '*.txt'
```

[How to filter git diff based on file extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554776/how-to-filter-git-diff-based-on-file-extensions) using JGit API.

From this answer, ([Equivalent of git diff in JGit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31325613/equivalent-of-git-diff-in-jgit)) I understood how to get the normal diff. But I would like to add the file extension  restriction to that  but I could not see anything in the `DiffCommand` doc (https://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/5.2.0.201812061821-r/apidocs/index.html).

Could some one please give some pointer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use a `DiffFormatter` as suggested in [Equivalent of git diff in JGit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31325613/equivalent-of-git-diff-in-jgit), you can specify a tree filter like this:

```java
TreeFilter treeFilter = PathSuffixFilter.create(".txt")

DiffFormatter diffFormatter = ...
diffFormatter.setPathFilter(treeFilter);
```

The example uses a `PathSuffixFilter` to exclude files ending with `.txt`.

Comment: Could you please have a look at the follow up question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54019259/jgit-how-to-reuse-the-diffformatter