# JGit - How to reuse the DiffFormatter

Tags: java, jgit

It's a followup question of [jgit - git diff based on file extension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54008247/jgit-git-diff-based-on-file-extension).

I am trying to add the formatted diff to `List<String>` but If I try to use same `DiffFormatter` as below then previous entries getting appended to the next one.

```
List<String> changes = new LinkedList<>();
            try (OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    DiffFormatter diffFormatter = new DiffFormatter(outputStream)) {
                diffFormatter.setRepository(git1.getRepository());
                TreeFilter treeFilter = PathSuffixFilter.create(".txt");
                diffFormatter.setPathFilter(treeFilter);
                List<DiffEntry> entries = diffFormatter.scan(newTree, oldTree);
                for (DiffEntry diffEntry : entries) {
                    diffFormatter.format(diffEntry);
                    changes.add(outputStream.toString());
                    diffFormatter.flush();
                }
            }
```

Therefore I forced to create a `DIffFormatter` for every diff entry.

Is there a better way to create `List<String> from List<DiffEntry>` without creating a new `DiffFormatter` every time?

Comment: You're using ByteArrayOutputStream here.  I think if you called OutputStream.reset() right after your diffFormatter.flush() line, you would get each entry individually rather than getting a cumulative result as you processed them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause for the previous entries getting appended is that the same output stream is used. Calling `outputStream.toString()` returns a string of all the bytes that have been written so far. Hence each calling `toString` within the for loop will return all previously created diffs, plus the current one.

I see two ways of solving this issue:

- Use a separate `DiffFormatter` within the for loop for each diff entry.
- Implement a custom `OutputStream` that allows to discard previously written content.

Comment: Thanks for confirming it.